# Gradle 2.1 is required Migrate to Gradle wrapper and sync project

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to build [u202](https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020) android project by Jake Wharton. My android studio is failing to build the project. The error being shown is as below:

```
Gradle 2.1 is required 
Migrate to Gradle wrapper and sync project
```

The line where error is shown points to `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` in the `build.gradle` file.

I have tried the following solutions but to no avail.

1. Run `gradlew` from the highest project directory. However when I run this from command line, I get a message that the build was successful but when I try to sync the project in android studio I get the above mentioned error.
2. Run gradle through command line. Since the gradle version I had in my path was of version 2.2.1, I got the error that plugin "com.android.application" cannot be found - I assume this is because I have this version of gradle-plugin in the project which needs to be updated to support newer version of gradle: 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.3'

Finally I could build the project by downloading gradle 2.1 manually and pointing the project to use local gradle instead of wrapper. I wanted to know if there is anything wrong in the way I tried to use gradle wrapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Settings -> Gradle` and click `Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)`. Press `Apply`.

After that go to `project-dir/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and change `distributionUrl` like so:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip
```

Try to `Build -> Make Project`.

You also may need to make sure that all components (Android Studio, Gradle itself and Android Gradle plugin) can be used together. Check out [this page](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility), here we can see that Gradle 2.1 can be used on Android Studio 0.9.0 - 0.9.3 and Gradle plugin has to be of version 0.14.0 - 0.14.4.

Comment: I already have that distribution url in the wrapper file: 

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip

Comment: @Supreethks try to enable gradle wrapper in project settings, I've added info on how to do it.

Comment: I did try that, enabled android studio to use wrapper and ran `Make Project` I got this build error : Error:(20) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'u2020'.
> Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.

Comment: @Supreethks try to update android gradle plugin in `build.gradle`  file also to one of the latest revisions. I used `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc4'` which works with the `Android Studio 1.0 RC 4` and project was imported w/o any issues.

Comment: Changed the version of gradle plugin also still no luck. The project builds fine if I use local instance of gradle 2.1. Still cant figure out what is the problem with my gradle wrapper :(

Comment: @Supreethks I've changed my answer, take a look at the the last paragraph.

Comment: Heard the latest release of Android studio has broken the myriad range of dependencies to version numbers. Hope a fresh install would work well. Accepting your answer as you have been very helpful.